# Laravel responsive drop down list

Tags: php, jquery, forms, select, laravel

I'm new to laravel and php so apologise if this is dumb (I'm a C# dev attempting to do some web development), Im making a form and I would like a drop down list to appear if a certain selection was made on another drop down list within the same form, I was hoping that someone could tell me how this is usually done, here is my code so far..

```
<h4>Select Object Type</h4>
{{ Form::select('shapeType', $Shapes) }}
@if($shapeType == "Triangle")
{{ Form::select('TriangleType', $TriangleTypes) }}
@endif
```

So as you can see, the first drop down list contains $Shapes which has a list of shapes and if Square is chosen I would like to show another drop down list where you can choose what type of triangle it is. So from my controller I populate $Shapes and $TriangleTypes, the current code gives me an error as $shapeType is undeclared and this is my poor attempt to read the previous drop down list. So some help would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Lando

Comment: you will need to use jQuery to do that see this(https://gist.github.com/msurguy/5138788)

Comment: thanks thats great, seems a bit overkill to to read one drop menu value but if thats how you do it then thats how I'm gonna do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with straight php because php is generated into html when it's loaded. It has no way to catch the change in the initial drop down.

Instead use javascript (with or without jQuery) to catch the change event that fires when a select option is chosen. Then use ajax to send the selected data to the server and retrieve the correct drop down data according to the data sent.

Code Example - note this is untested and may have some errors in it but hopefully it'll be enough to get you started.

```
Route::get('/shapes', array(
    'uses' => 'ExampleController@myShapes'  
));

class ExampleController extends BaseController{
    public function myShapes{
    if(Request::ajax()){
        $type = Input::get('shapeType');

        switch($shapeType){
        case 'triangle':
             //get triangle data
             break;
        case 'square':
             //get square data
             break;
        default:
            //invalid input sent
            break;
        }
        return $data;
    }
    }
}

$('#shapeType').change(function(){
    shapeValue = //get value from the selected item
    $.ajax({
        url: '/shapes',
        data: shapeValue
        success: function(result){
            //change/update drop down to result data
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your welcome. Glad to help. Note - madam would be more appropriate. :)

Comment: Apologies Madam, I've never come across a female programmer myself but I've been told they exist and that there all totally hot ;)